# Doom 3 codebase release details

Tags: open-source

Does anyone know when the source code for Doom 3 is to be released?
I've heard a lot of things but nothing conclusive.

Thanks
Adam

**Edit** any info is appreciated

Comment: Unless there's someone from Id on the site any answer is going to be at best a guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are planning to [GPL the id Tech 4 engine in 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech_4)

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [id's SDK website](http://www.iddevnet.com/doom3/code.php):

> The Code is where all the real fun starts to happen. The Doom 3 SDK comes with pretty much half the source code for the game.

So the full source code hasn't been released yet, but some of it has.

Answer (score 0):

[Doom 3 Downloads](http://www.iddevnet.com/doom3/downloads.php)

Not sure if that's just modding stuff, or extensions, but it does say SDK 3 'Contains the **game source code**, expansion source code (Resurrection of Evil), maya importer source, vehicle demo, and sample Maya files'.

If that just means far enough to mod it, I do not know.